# Calling fragment's onActivityResult from activity to pass data to fragment, method is deprecated

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, deprecated, onactivityresult

I'm trying to pass data I received in activity to fragment in the following manner

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    myFragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
}
```

However, `myFragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)` is deprecated. How can I send the data to fragment level without using deprecated code?

Comment: Did you read the [Communicating with Fragments guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate)?

Comment: onActivityResult is deprecated. Google proposed a new way to handle activity results. Please read the implementation guide https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a fragment listener instead. Like this:

```
                parentFragmentManager.setFragmentResultListener(
                "YOUR_REQUEST_KEY",
                viewLifecycleOwner
            ) { requestKey, result ->
                if (requestKey == "YOUR_REQUEST_KEY") {
                    //Do whatever you could previously do in this section in onActivityResult
                }
            }
```

and when you want to set the result do this:

```
    val bundle = Bundle()
    //Put your data in bundle here
    setFragmentResult("YOUR_REQUEST_KEY", bundle)
```